Lemma 2 of Halmos and Savage: Structure theorem for measurable maps only applies when points are measurable.
I am having some trouble following the proof of Lemma 2 in this paper by Halmos and Savage, which I include here

$E$ is defined as the preimage under $f$ of a point in $\mathbb{R}$. They use the measurability of $f$ to conclude that $E$ is a set in $T^{-1}(\mathbf{T})$. This is allowable only because singletons in $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable. In the footnote shown here

they mention that the restriction to real-valued functions is "inessential". But it seems to me to be very consequential: earlier in the paper they establish that Euclidean spaces will always be endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, in which points are measurable. But if the co-domain of $f$ is some other measurable space in which singletons are not measurable, this step of the argument would fail. Could someone confirm or refute this for me?
